# Can't open SQL Server DB Objects from Visual Web Developer 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-web-developer

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010.

I created a sql server connection to a remote server but I can't open or create any DB objects. I get the message:
This feature is not supported by Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do it from Visual Web Developer. Download and install MS SQL Managament Studio Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593)